# How to get Array Json in Ionic2

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I want to get the translatedText value. But in the console.log keep show undefined. w

```
this.getPosts('Hello', 'ja');

getPosts(text, category) {
  this.translateService.getPosts(text, category).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response.data.translations.translateText);
    this.items = response.data.translations;
    console.log(items.translateText)
```

}
Here's the Json Format.

```
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "Hallo Welt",
        "detectedSourceLanguage": "en"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: We have no idea of what this.translateService.getPosts() does. Why don't you just print `response` (or inspect it with your debugger), and see what it actually contains?

Comment: I think **this.items = response.data.translations;** should be **this.items = response.data.translations[0];**

Comment: i just wan to get the data from the items.translation.translatedText. but when i console.log(this.items.translations.translatedText) it show undefined.....